# Angular 4: Updating the view

Tags: html, angular, typescript, data-binding

I'm very new to web-development in general, but I'm trying to build my website and came across the following problem I haven't be able to solve. I'm using angular 4
I have a div highlighting some code in my html file:

```
<div *ngIf="step1Updated">
  <prism-block 
    [code]="step1" 
    [language]="'python'">
  </prism-block>
  {{ step1 }}
</div>
```

In my typescript file:

```
step1Updated = false;
step1 = '';

onStep1(fileType: string) {
    this.step1 = this.step1service.returnCode(this.language, fileType);
    this.step1Updated = true;
}
```

Now on my html page, when I click from a selection of buttons executing `onStep1()` with different content, the content within my string interpolation changes, the `{{ step1 }}`, but the content within my `prism-block` doesn't. I can see that this is because we need two-way databinding but I've tried to put the `[(ngModel)]="step1"` two way data binding in the prism-block, div, etc... hoping that it would catch the update and then update the block, same as putting code in `[(code)]` but all resulted in errors..

any help or advice would be really appreciated!

Comment: you can't use `ngModel` outside of `forms`, show your `prism-block` component definition

Comment: I did not create the prism-block component, it was installed via https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-prism, with the imports and declaration being in the app.module.ts.

Comment: there's something wrong with `prism` component, can you put up a plunker?

Comment: I've never used plunker, I just tried to but it works nothing like the angular I've been using.. My prism works, it highlights code from multiple languages fine, just if change the content of a string, it wont show the updated content.

Comment: drop here the link to the plunker you created

Comment: plnkr.co/pN9UJ9b6Syq4pzaJR5H8

Comment: so what am I looking for there?

Comment: I have two buttons, upon clicking one it will show step1 string in the prism-code and through string interpolation, but if i then select the other button, the step1 string will not change within the prism-code, but does change in string interpolation

Comment: right now the plunker doesn't update the value with neither button

Comment: Yeah thats what I was trying to say, I haven't used Plunker before and it works nothing like the way I use angular on my laptop. So I just showed the code of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TUEyDtBG56wJuL26DEUV?p=preview) you have fully function angular plunker application, add your code and ensure it works, then I'll take a look

Comment: Apologies, but I still couldn't get it all to work on Plunker, like getting the services and prism to all work..

Comment: no problem, I just won't be able to help without seeing the problem reproduced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
here you need to load PrismComponent dynamically to update its view.refer my plunker(http://plnkr.co/edit/tEgnnS) code.


    onStep1(fileType: string) {
    const crf = this.cfR.resolveComponentFactory(PrismComponent);
    this.cc.clear();
    const cf = this.cc.createComponent(crf);
    (<PrismComponent>cf.instance).code = this.step1service.returnCode(this.language, fileType);
  }
```

Comment: refer app template and its component, don't forget to add entryComponent in app module

Comment: Worked perfectly, repeating the last line to load the language dynamically too. Now I will study your code to fully understand it. Thank you so much!